# When printing an array in Kotlin, instead of printing the integer, it prints a slew of other characters

Tags: arrays, kotlin

```
package MiscellaneousProjects

import java.util.*

class Numbers(val numbers: Int){
}

fun ClosedRange<Int>.random() = Random().nextInt((endInclusive + 1) - start) +  start // Function to randomly generate a number

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var list = arrayListOf<Numbers>()
    for(i in 1..10){
        val random = Random()
        list.add(Numbers((0..100).random())) // Adds the numbers to an array
    }

    var sortedList = list.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.numbers })) // Sorts the elements from least to greatest

    for(element in sortedList){
        println(element.numbers) // Prints the individual entries
    }

    println(sortedList)

}
```

The following piece of code picks a number from 0 to 100 and adds it to an array.

I am sorting the numbers from greatest to least using sortedWith and compareBy functions. However, when I print "sortedList," the following types of entries are seen: "MiscellaneousProjects.Numbers@30f39991, MiscellaneousProjects.Numbers@452b3a41."

However, whenever I print the individual elements in the array, it outputs the correct numbers.

Can someone tell me the error in my code?

Answer (score 2):

Either use a [`data class`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) for `Numbers` (which basically has a built-in `toString()` that will probably suffice your needs already) or just override `toString()` yourself in the `Numbers` class to return the `numbers`, e.g.

```
override fun toString() = numbers.toString()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: feel free to upvote if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're relying on the default implementation of `toString` for your `Numbers` class, which is inherited from `Object` and prints what you see (i.e., `<class_name>@<hash_code>`, as you can find [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java)).

To print something more meaningful you can override the `toString` method (or `fun` in Kotlin) to return the `String` you're expecting

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!